# EMR issues with reducer.py

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I'm running AWS and trying to run a simulation on the EMR setting. I know my mapper.py file is correct but I can't seem to figure out why my reducer.py file isn't correctly working.. The idea was to sort a movies.cvs file that holds data from IMDB and find the worst 20 movies from a voting and rating perspective. I've been trying to figure out why my code isn't working and would love some help if possible. All logs show that my mapper.py file is running correctly but not the reducer.py. I have included the code for my reducer.py. Thank you for the help.

UPDATED***

### reducer.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
from operator import itemgetter


arraysize = 20

results_printed = [('x', int(0), 'x')]

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()   
  title, votes, rating = line.split("\t")   
  try:
        results = (title, int(votes), rating)
        results_printed.append(results)
  except ValueError:    pass
results_printed = sorted(results_printed, key=itemgetter(1))
for q in range (0,arraysize):
    print(results_printed[q])
```

Comment: What is `arraysize` used for?

Comment: solely for the number 20 in the for loop

Comment: You did not fix indentation yet. The problem is probably `sorted(results_printed, key=itemgetter('votes'))`. What is `'votes'`?

Comment: 'Votes' is the number of votes for each movie based on the movies.cvs file that is the input file for EMR

Comment: How are they fetched from `results_printed`? Should it not be: `sorted(results_printed, key=itemgetter(1))` ? Also, you can change `int(0)` to `0`.

Comment: Would it be 1 if 'Votes' is the 5th column in the cvs file? This is my first time using itemgetter so it's new to me

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what is your desired behaviour and how your code fails the expected behaviour. 'not working' is not enough.

Comment: And **please** fix indentation. Look at your code. The indentation is **not** fixed.

Comment: I have kind of fixed my code a little bit to where I get three separate output files as opposed to the one with the 20 results... This is what it looks like now.